# using sharedpreferences from service

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use sharedpreferences from my thread called by service:

```
SharedPreferences startPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            //SharedPreferences startPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
            startPref.edit().putString("REFRESHED", when);
            startPref.edit().commit();
            System.out.println("Time put " + when);
            System.out.println("Got time " + startPref.getString("REFRESHED", "WRONG"));
```

I try to put there some string and then take it back, but I always get WRONG default message. I've tried to use both variants of startPref initializing: commented and not, both don't work.

context is service's Context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
startPref.edit().putString("REFRESHED", when);
startPref.edit().commit();
```

to

```
startPref.edit().putString("REFRESHED", when).commit();
```

Each call to `edit()` creates a new `SharedPreferences.Editor` instance. So, you are leaving your changes uncommitted in one and committing no changes in another editor.